# How can use the xml file outputed by CoreNLP

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I intended first POS tagging a document and then extract nouns or noun phrases, then find the frequent nouns or noun pharsess. What language should I use? is there some package or lib I can use?

Comment: use GATE (https://gate.ac.uk/). It comes with tones of ready-to-use features (i.e. POS tagger, NE transducer, etc) and allows you to implement your own modules in Java and add them as a component of its pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Opennlp for your purpose, easy to use and you can find a lot of support!

Refer to this [blog](http://harmeetsingh13.blogspot.in/2013/05/search-noun-adjectives-verbs-from-text.html)

It has code using opennlp to extract nouns,verbs and Adjectives.

Hope this helps.